# How to use If & AND formular for decimal in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a column with several decimal numbers like:

```
A1: 0.48
A2: 1.13
A3: 4.31
A4: 5.89
```

I want to find a number is in a specific set range. If yes give a specific letter out. I tried this formular but this doesnt work for decimal. For non decimal numbers it works well:

```
=IF(A1>=10;"A";IF(AND(A1>=7;4.31<=8);"B";IF(AND(A1>=4;4.31<=3);"C";IF(A1<=0;"D"))))
```

But it shows for every number "A". Why?

Comment: Is your locale set to use `.` as decimal point, or is it `,`? If it is `,`, then your numbers are not numbers. One way to see this is that they don't align to the right (unless you format the cell that way). If this is your case, enter numbers with `,` decimal separator instead of `.`

Comment: Your formula cannot work like you say it does. `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` should be in quotes (unless they are named ranges??). Can you make sure you present a formula that is syntactically correct?

Comment: @trincot Youre right, I edit my post but the problems are the same. I work with variables in the original formular – this here is only a example for demonstration what my problem ist.

Comment: What about my first comment?

Comment: That doesnt work :/

Comment: No, I mean, the question: what is your locale decimal delimeter? Is your locale set to use `.` as decimal point, or is it `,`?

Comment: I changed to the US version, I am german. I tried both but it doesnt work. Should it work with my formular? Is it normally right?

Comment: It should work. Are the numbers in column A recognised as numbers? Like, can you make a sum of them with a sum formula?

Comment: The last `IF` is missing a third argument though...

Comment: As far as I understand your ranges are: A if value >= 10, B if value is between 8 and 7, C if value is >=4 and <=3 (which is always FALSE in an AND statement), D if value <= 0. If you check your formula for the case above, you should always get FALSE if the value is a number as all conditions are FALSE and there is no value in the last if statement in case condition is FALSE. As @trincot said here above if your cells contains text (the case of decimal separator in locale set), you will get "A". At last please also check all conditions as you put values instead of cell references.